# Выделение строчек таблицы через клик, ctrl и shift

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь сделать выделение строчек таблицы через клик, ctrl и shift

```js
jQuery("#samples_data_div").on('click', '#samples_data_table tbody tr', function(e) {
  if (!e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey) {
    console.log('standart');
    $(this).parent().find('tr').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }

  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    console.log('ctrl');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  }

  if (e.shiftKey) {
    console.log('shift');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.active {
  background-color: #337ab7;
}

table tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #57a1e0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="samples_data_div">
  <table id="samples_data_table" border=1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1 столбец</th>
        <th>2 столбец</th>
        <th>3 столбец</th>
        <th>4 столбец</th>
        <th>5 столбец</th>
        <th>6 столбец</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-sample_id="78">
        <td>центр</td>
        <td class="warning">4</td>
        <td>Наша</td>
        <td>13.10.2017</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-sample_id="79">
        <td>центр</td>
        <td class="warning">5</td>
        <td>Наша</td>
        <td>14.10.2017</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-sample_id="80">
        <td>центр</td>
        <td class="warning">6</td>
        <td>Наша</td>
        <td>14.10.2017</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Но как быть с shift? Как определить с каком позиции начали и какой закончили? Была идея использовать `$(this).closest('tr').index()`, но как узнавать с какого индекса началось выделение? Или как-то иначе сделать это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил когда выбираешь первую строку, сохранить его индекс. После когда при нажатой клавише `shift` выбираешь следующую строку то посмотреть его индекс больше или меньше начального, и наконец пройтись по циклу по строкам и дать класс `active` тем строкам индекс которых находится между выбранными строками.

```js
var select_start_index = -1;
jQuery("#samples_data_div").on('click', '#samples_data_table tbody tr', function(e) {
  var t_rows = $(this).parent().find('tr');
  if (!e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey) {
    t_rows.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    select_start_index = t_rows.index(this);
  }

  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    console.log('ctrl');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  }

  if (e.shiftKey) {
    var select_end_index = t_rows.index(this);
    var each_start, each_end;
    if(select_start_index != -1){
      console.log('shift');
      if(select_start_index < select_end_index){
        each_start = select_start_index;
        each_end = select_end_index;
      }
      else{
        each_start = select_end_index;
        each_end = select_start_index;
      }
      t_rows.each(function(index){
        if(index >= each_start && index <= each_end){
          $(this).addClass('active');
        }
      });
    }
    
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.active {
  background-color: #337ab7;
}

table tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #57a1e0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="samples_data_div">
  <table id="samples_data_table" border=1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1 столбец</th>
        <th>2 столбец</th>
        <th>3 столбец</th>
        <th>4 столбец</th>
        <th>5 столбец</th>
        <th>6 столбец</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-sample_id="78">
        <td>центр</td>
        <td class="warning">4</td>
        <td>Наша</td>
        <td>13.10.2017</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-sample_id="79">
        <td>центр</td>
        <td class="warning">5</td>
        <td>Наша</td>
        <td>14.10.2017</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-sample_id="80">
        <td>центр</td>
        <td class="warning">6</td>
        <td>Наша</td>
        <td>14.10.2017</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-sample_id="78">
        <td>центр</td>
        <td class="warning">4</td>
        <td>Наша</td>
        <td>13.10.2017</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-sample_id="79">
        <td>центр</td>
        <td class="warning">5</td>
        <td>Наша</td>
        <td>14.10.2017</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-sample_id="80">
        <td>центр</td>
        <td class="warning">6</td>
        <td>Наша</td>
        <td>14.10.2017</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```